# How does one implement a c++ wrapper into C#

Tags: c#, c++, design-patterns, wrapper

I am working on a project where I need to use a wrapper written in C++ to transfer messages across servers through c# code. The client applications are written in c#, but the message bus that I have to use doesn't work directly with .NET, so C++ wrapper to the rescue.

I hope that this makes sense, and any help would be great. Thanks

Comment: Calling .NET code from C++ code is called "[COM Callable Wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f07c8z1c.aspx)" by MS. The inverse is called "[Runtime Callable Wrappers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bwh56xe.aspx)". This is a rather broad subject - there are multiple ways to do this. I suggest that you research a bit and then try posting specific questions.

Comment: @metacubed Good point. Note that CCW is not always the answer. Direct interop OR having Managed C++ wrapper are other approaches.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Of course. I would also suggest PInvoke or C++/CLI (my preference), but I would prefer that the poster discovered their joys on his own :).

Comment: @AlexiLevonkov I guess I did not express myself as I intended. I'm not asking how to access dll's in C# project. I edited my original post. Hopefully that makes it a little more clear

Comment: It looks like you are asking how to use some random piece of code... Since you figured all wrappers it looks like you should have good knowledge of both C# and C++ - so write/debug (or find) sample of using in C++ first and than translate as necessary to C# using your wrappers... Or you asking for something totally different?

Comment: I guess what I'm asking for is resources on the concept of "wrapping". What do I do with my Wrapper class exactly? Also, there's no example, I was pretty much handed this code that no one really tested in the way that I need to use it.

Comment: It's not at all clear what you're trying to do, so it's impossible to say what you're wrapping. You say that the message bus doesn't work with .NET, but then you say that the C# applications send messages by calling C++ DLLs. So does the sending work okay and you need help receiving? It's impossible to tell from your question exactly the problem lies.

Answer (score 2):

You can call C++ contained in a dll from C# using Platform Invoke. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288468%28v=vs.71%29.aspx. In this case it is actually the C# code wrapping the C++ code.

Comment: I guess I did not express myself as I intended. I'm not asking how to access dll's in C# project. I edited my original post. Hopefully that makes it a little more clear